# How to define two authentication mechanism for different routes in Spring Security 6?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-3, security-filter

All routing files config, except for /actuator/**, the entry point is of type ***"JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint"*** (Custom defined)

```
    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .cors(cors -> {})
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
                    auth.requestMatchers("**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .exceptionHandling(handler -> handler.defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(entryPoint, new AntPathRequestMatcher("**")))
            .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .headers(headers -> headers.cacheControl(cacheControl -> {}));

        return http.build();
    }
```

Security config for actuator routes, the entry point is of Type ***"AuthenticationEntryPoint"***

```
  @Bean
  @Order(2)
  public SecurityFilterChain actuatorSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .cors(cors -> {})
        .authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
                auth.requestMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
        )
        .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
        .exceptionHandling(handler -> handler.defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(entryPoint, new AntPathRequestMatcher("/actuator/**")))
        .anonymous(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);

    return http.build();
  }
```

basically if one bean loads first then it overrides the other one. If I change the swap the order of the beans then actuator would work fine and other routes won't. I assume it is the problem of misconfiguring of entry point of authentication for both routes.

Comment: I think in your current configuration you might have a conflict with your requestMatchers. What you could try adding to `actuatorSecurityFilterChain` `http.securityMatcher("/actuator")`. 
This tells spring to only apply this chain given the pattern.

Comment: `jwtAuthenticationFilter` writing a custom jwt filter and using jwts as sessions is very dangerous and very insecure and should not be done. This "solution" should be removed. Whatever blogpost/tutorial you are following has no idea how security works.

Comment: Thank you @Simon bro so much, it solved the problem for me, I was stuck on it for few days.

Comment: @Toerktumlare can you please explain more on how jwt and all you said is insecure? I am still a bit naïve to spring security, waiting to listen to your reply on it,

Comment: I cant explain how spring security works. Stack overflow is a Q&A site, not a forum. I would recommend that you read the spring security documentation if you wish to learn spring security. And to understand why jwts are insecure just google why they shouldnt be used as sessions. Spring security is security framework, it has built in handling for jwts the correct way, and using jwts as sessions is the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach for resolving this is to use the `securityMatcher`

Using your example code:

```java
 @Bean
  @Order(2)
  public SecurityFilterChain actuatorSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .securityMatcher("/actuator")
        .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .cors(cors -> {})
        .authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
                auth.requestMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
        )
        .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
        .exceptionHandling(handler -> handler.defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(entryPoint, new AntPathRequestMatcher("/actuator/**")))
        .anonymous(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);

    return http.build();
  }
```

This will ensure that the provided security chain will only be applied to routes matching the pattern provided.

Comment: Yes it solved my problem, also I swapped order numbers of both beans as the bean with name "securityFilterChain" is matching for "**" so it will override the "actuatorSecurityFilterChain" if it is initialized first.